# Handling Method Call on Invalid Object

Tags: java, exception

I have a Container and an Item class that are acted upon by a World. I intend for an Item to be in a Container's inventory (Collection). Most items are movable (able to be swapped from one Container to another); other items are note movable. Each Item defines a method, isMovable(), that returns true if the Item is movable, and false otherwise. When I write the method in Container to swap an item to another Container, what is the best way to handle the case when this swapItem() method is called on an immovable Item?

Here is my code so far:

```
**
 * Used by the World class to swap the an {@link Item} between this 
 * container and another (the destination).
 *  
 * @param item The Item to be swapped to the destination
 * @param dest The destination (i.e. recipient) container
 */
public final void swapItem(Item item, Container dest){
    if (item.isTakeable()){
        this.f_contents.remove(item);
        dest.getContents().add(item);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I chose to throw an exception which I can catch if the World class calls swap on an immovable item. Is IllegalStateexception the correct exception to throw in this case? Would it have been better to simply check isTakeable() in a method of the World class before calling swapItem() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is a design decision and I have seen several approaches taken in such situations.
It is perfectly legitimate case to throw an exception if you clearly document it for your API.
You could also indicate success of operation by returning boolean.

Consider, for instance, Java Collections framework, let say Queue interface.
For element insertion there are twin methods :

- [offer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer(E)) that will return boolean to indicate succcess (or false if queue was already full)
- [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add(E)) that will throw an exception instead

Answer (score 0):

Its not a wrong approach, but its not a clean approach either (in my opinion).

I generally only throw IllegalStateExceptions/IllegalArgumentExceptions/etc, if I think something went seriously wrong for execution to get to that point with a certain state.

I don't think it is unreasonable to want to move an item, and do it to a non-moveable item (although the caller *should* call isMoveable first).

I think you could probably either have 2 subclass of Item:

```
public class MoveableItem extends Item {
  public final void swapItem (Container dest){
    // - remove Item from src (I'm assuming if you did this, you would have a reference to src)
    // - add to dest
  }
}
```

and

```
public class NonMoveableItem extends Item { ... }
```

where MoveableItem contains a move method, and NonMoveableItem does not.

Or, you can change swapItem to return a boolean or int, and return false or -1 or something if it fails (Note: If I'm not mistaken, boolean still takes up 32 bits in Java,  under the hood - so I frequently take advantage of int to signify how a function fails more explicitly, rather than just false for *any* failure).